# HTTP Content-Length and Chunked Transfer-Encoding. Is there a 2GB Limit?

Tags: http, chunked-encoding, http-content-length, http-chunked

Is a HTTP `Content-Length` **over 2GB** or **4GB** supported by modern webservers?

How about the chunks in HTTP *Chunked* Transfer Encoding? Can an *individual HTTP chunk* exceed **2GB** in length?

I need to know to use `32-bit integers` or `64-bit integers` in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have gathered, 64-bit limits are new, especially in the web browsers. Chrome supports them, Opera maybe, and I see a patch for Firefox that hasn't landed yet. I've read posts that say IE returns negative `Content-Length`, which means it's likely to use 32-bits.

64-bit HTTP lengths looks like the future, but we aren't there yet.