# Limit on the length of the data that a webserver can return in response to a GET request

Tags: http, rest, webserver, jetty

I have a **REST** service running on jetty server that responds to **GET** requests with some resource data. So far the data that i retrieve has been in the order of a few kb. I am looking to use a similar REST service that could possibly return huge data, may be a 100 mb or more. No memory issues expected since the request volume is low and both the jetty server and rest client processes have been configured with enough memory.

I am wondering if jetty or any webserver in general places a restriction on the length of data it can return to the client in response to a GET. If so, is it configurable in jetty?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

There are no limits on the amount of data returned on a HTTP response from Jetty.

You could stream data back to the client until shortly before the [heat death of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe).

Technically speaking, you can have a HTTP Response with no `Content-Length` specified, which can be returned using either the [Chunked Transfer-Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), or just a raw stream of bytes with a `Connection: close` indicating when the data is complete (done being sent) by a close of the underlying connection.  Both of which are essentially limit-less.

If you use a HTTP Response with `Content-Length` header, be aware that Content-Length is, [in practice, a 32-bit number, but more modern browsers support the 64-bit versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811824/http-content-length-and-chunked-transfer-encoding-is-there-a-2gb-limit).

**Update (August 2019):**

Jetty 9.4.20.v20190813 can now handle `Content-Length` headers of maximum size [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) ([9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9,223,372,036,854,775,807) bytes)

Comment: and does the tomcat has response limit?

Comment: With a response of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes, and an average download speed of 25mbps (which is the high end of the average) ~= 3,125,000 bytes/second, it would take about 187,181.5736 years to download that response.