# Is the size of GET data limited only for the call or also in the response?

Tags: php, get

I've seen that GET requests are size limited due to the browser not accepting excessively long urls.

But is there also a limitation in size **in the response** ($_GET)?

Comment: In what format are you returning the response?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get

Comment: Formatted in json response

Comment: ...and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172524/limit-on-the-length-of-the-data-that-a-webserver-can-return-in-response-to-a-get

Comment: your link to another question doesn't answer mine, I ask for the response, I know that the url parameters are limited.

Comment: @hherger thanks that what I was looking for, no limit at all, thanks a lot

Comment: Then they have no limitations see this [json size limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per response in the the comments on your question. If your responses are in json format. Then they have no limitations.

See this : [Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)

And [Limit on the length of the data that a webserver can return in response to a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172524/limit-on-the-length-of-the-data-that-a-webserver-can-return-in-response-to-a-get)

You may want to take a look at this to see how different browsers perform with large json responses 
[how-big-is-too-big-for-json](http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/)