# Large GET requests

Tags: sql, .net, http, service

Im writing a serivce which can hold more than 100k. data in one table.
And there should be a getAllDataMethod() which should return this to the user.

But im sure this is not right to do this, because my response body could be to big so the user had to wait to long.

> 1.Is there any rule for a sql select limit or a response body size limit to keep the UX high.
>
> 2.Should there never be a "getAllData()" methode in big tables(10k?),instead of this there should be a lazy load method like
>   "getAllData(string searchBy, int currentRow)" with a limit on the
>   select

Comment: there is a good answer on the size limit (or lack thereof) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172524/limit-on-the-length-of-the-data-that-a-webserver-can-return-in-response-to-a-get

Comment: You should use pagination on any request that returns a large number of results.